# GoCardless setup Direct Debit mandate and subscription at the same time

Tags: php, gocardless

I'm using PHP to setup a Direct Debit Mandate via the GoCardless API, but I cannot figure out how to automatically setup a subscription against that mandate.

First I create a billing request:

```
$br = $client->billingRequests()->create([
  "params" => [
    "mandate_request" => [
      "scheme" => "bacs",
      "currency" => "GBP",
    ]
  ]
]);
```

Then I create a Billing Request Flow:

```
$brf = $client->billingRequestFlows()->create([
  "params" => [
    "redirect_uri" => "http://localhost/success",
    "exit_uri" => "http://localhost/exit",
    "links" => [
      "billing_request" => $br->id
    ],
    "prefilled_customer" => [
          "email" => "alice@example.com",
          "given_name" => "Alice",
          "family_name" => "Smith",
    ],
  ]
]);
```

Then I redirect the customer to the authorization URL:

```
header("Location: " . $brf->authorisation_url);
```

The customer completes their details on the GoCardless hosted page, which sets up a mandate, but no payment is taken. I have to manually login to the dashboard to assign a subscription against the customer's mandate.

What I would like to do is create/assign the subscription at the same time as creating the mandate.  This doesn't look to be possible, but I am wondering what other options are available.  It seems strange to have to assign the subscription manually after the mandate is created.

Comment: GoCardless does not allow to do this. Only one-time payments are allowed to be created alongside the mandate.

Comment: Correct, seems like a bit of a limitation really.  Because once the mandate is setup someone has to manually intervene to setup the regular payments.